# How to logout of linkedin using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to logout from linkedin using the following code, but it is giving me this error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

The login is successful but it does nothing about the logout code and exits.

```html
  

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Shivam\Documents\scrapin\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?goback=&trk=hb_signin')

driver.maximize_window()

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')


email.send_keys('******')

time.sleep(3)

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
password.send_keys('*******')


time.sleep(3)

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app__container"]/main/div/form/div[3]/button')
login.click()

time.sleep(3)

logout = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1016"]')
logout.click()
```

Comment: On the last line you are retrieving a list of element.
```logout = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1016"]')```.
Remove the 's' from ```find_element(s)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rely  on those ember ID's because they are dynamically generated when the page loads.  For example, when I load the page the Sign Out button has `id="ember1203"`.  Plus, you'll need to click the button to open the dropdown where Sign Out is before you can click it.  Try the following instead of your current logout code:

```
dropdownButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#nav-settings__dropdown-trigger')
dropdownButton.click()
signoutButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href="/m/logout/"]')
signoutButton.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I want to ask one more thing. How to click on the button that has no ahref link in the code for example the home button or My network button on linkedin.
Thanks in advance!